# DataGridView ComboBox Column Selection Disappears After Dataadapter Update

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, oledb

So i have a Status column on my DataGridView.
The DataGridView is populated by data from a SQL server including a status column.
My goal was to convert that column from a TextBox column to a ComboBox column.
Basically what i did was:

1. Insert a new ComboBox column.
2. Copy data from the TextBox column (populated from server) to ComboBox column.
3. Hide TextBox column.
4. Updated the TextBox column with changes done on the ComboBox column.
5. Update the database using the dataadpter and the TextBox column.

It might not be pretty but it works and i couldn't find better ideas online.

my only issue now is that after updating the database (using OleDB) , the selection in the ComboBox columns defaults to Nothing instead of what was actually there before.

Row before database update:
[image]

And row after database update:
[image]

And this is the update code:

```
    Private Sub ReqUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReqUpdate.Click

    'This method updates the database with changes made in DVGrequestsSQL.
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Try
        cmdReqBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daReq)
        changes = dsReq.GetChanges()
        If changes IsNot Nothing Then
            daReq.Update(dsReq.Tables(0))
        End If
        dsReq.AcceptChanges()
        Label11.Visible = False
        Me.DGVrequestsSQL.Columns("StatusQ").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        MsgBox("Updates saved successfuly!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Now column "StatusQ" is not part of the DataSet (the DataSet Status column is hidden) and i have no idea why the selection defaults to nothing and no idea how to fix it.
Anyone might have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that after the update is done, the DataGridView is automatically refreshed.  Since you are manually populating/setting/updating the ComboBox, you'll have to repeat that step.

Comment: That's what i ended up doing... thanks!